# Twilio SDK App Auth

Tags: twilio

Is it possible to authenticate to Twilio using an App SID and Secret when using the SDK?

Or do you have to use Account SID and Key when using the SDK?

We want to use:

```
API Key Sid: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

API Key Secret: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

But it seems we have to use:

```
Account Sid: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Account Auth Token: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The docs say that the API Key can be used for the REST API - can it work for SDK access as well?

We are using SDK for Node

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can absolutely use an API SID and Secret to authenticate to Twilio. With [the Node.js Twilio package](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node) you would do this:

```
const twilio = require('twilio');

const apiKey = process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY;
const apiSecret = process.env.TWILIO_API_SECRET;
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;

const client = twilio(apiKey, apiSecret, { accountSid: accountSid });
```

You do still need to add the Account SID as an argument, because resources are namespaced behind the Account SID, but this is how you initialise a client in this case.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Ahah!  You have to add the account SID as well.  That's what we were doing wrong.  Docs could be clearer ;-)  thanks Phil!

Comment: Yeah, I struggled to find where this was referenced in the docs too. I'll see if I can get that added somewhere

Comment: Sounds like a plan!

Comment: Ah, found it! There's an example here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/keys?code-sample=code-use-an-api-key-pair-to-send-a-message&code-language=js&code-sdk-version=3.x